# Recursion in java missing a return statement?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

```
private int yo ( int [] arr, int i){
    if(arr[i]!=0){  
         arr[i+2]=arr[i]+arr[i+1];
         yo(arr, i+2);
    }else{
       return -1; 
    }

}
```

Why am I missing a return statement?

Comment: Well, what does the function return when `arr[i]!=0`?

Comment: In the if block you need to add a return statement. Or else after the else block would be fine too.

Comment: Recursion is ugly concept that should be used sparsingly. If you can iterate, iterate. 9 out 10 times the solution to your problem is more clear without using recursion, though it adds few more lines and steps inbetween.
So my advice is to try and solve your problem through iteration first and if that fails, then try to debug your recursion.

Comment: I believe you're missing `return yo(arr, i+2)`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `return` statement in your `if` block.

In general recursion works like:

```
private int recursiveMethod (int a){
   // your code goes here

   return recursiveMethod (..);
}
```

From what I can understand from your code, you don't actually have to use recursion so try doing it using iterations.

Anyway in your case your code should be:

```
private int yo ( int [] arr, int i){
    if(arr[i]!=0){  
         arr[i+2]=arr[i]+arr[i+1];
         return yo(arr, i+2);
    }else{
       return -1; 
    }

}
```